# Phonegap android device connection check in background

Tags: android, cordova, connection, background-process

I'm developing an app in which i need to check the device network connection status.
I need to call a webservice whenever the device comes online form offline state.

I'm using HTML5 `navigator.onLine` and Phonegap `navigator.connection.type` properties.

This checking is working fine, when the app is opened and running.
How can i check the same thing even if the app is not opened.

Comment: Have you figured it out somehow?

Answer (score 0):

you have device eventlistener function for detecting online and offline internet connectivity of the device in the phonegap API.

[For online event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online)

[For Offline event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @chris- but the condition is when application is not opened I think. Background events.

Comment: Yes, The check should be in background, i'm already using the above events.... that are working when the app is open and running...

Comment: My requirement is, i need to send the data stored in offline to server  whenever the device has a connection...